# Using QR and NFC technology together in an Android app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am developing an Android app consisting of two activites so far. The first activity (MainActivity) is started when the app is launched or when a QR code is scanned. The MainActivity starts the second activity (NFCActivity) when the user presses a button. The NFCActivity waits for the user to tap a NFC token, reads out data from the token, and returns the read data to the MainActivity.

This works fine if the app is started manually. If the app is started by scanning a QR code, taping the NFC tag does not invoke the NFCActivity's onNewIntent() method as exepcted, but instead creates a new instance of the NFCActivity on top of the already displayed one.

The enableForegroundDispatch() method is called and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP should be set. Relevant source code of a minimal example is provided below. Any help would be highly appreciated!

*MainActivity:*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText dataRead;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        dataRead = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data);

        final Button readKeyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readNFC);
        readKeyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent keyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    NFCActivity.class);
                keyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                startActivityForResult(keyIntent, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            String result =     intent.getExtras().getString("resultData");
        this.dataRead.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

*Main Activity's GUI:*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readNFC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="127dp"
        android:text="Read NFC Tag" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/readNFC"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*NFCActivity:*

```
public class NFCActivity extends Activity {

    private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private IntentFilter[] mFilters;
    private String[][] mTechLists;  


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.read_nfc);

        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

        // // Setup an intent filter for all MIME based dispatches
        IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        try {
            ndef.addDataType("*/*");
        } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
        }
        IntentFilter td = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        mFilters = new IntentFilter[] { ndef, td };
        //
        // // Setup a tech list for all NfcF tags
        mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcV.class.getName(),
                NfcF.class.getName(), NfcA.class.getName(),
                NfcB.class.getName() } };

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        if (mAdapter != null)           
            mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, mFilters,
                    mTechLists);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        if (mAdapter != null)
            mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.d("TEST", "onNewIntent() called.");

        // READ THE NFC TAG HERE [SKIPPED FOR MINIMAL EXAMPLE]

        // Return dummy data for test
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra("resultData", "DUMMY DATA");

        setResult(1, result);
        finish();
    }   


}
```

*NFCActivity's GUI:*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Tap your NFC tag.."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FF8811"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.nfcqrtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="test.nfcqrtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="test.org" android:pathPrefix="/testapp" />
            </intent-filter>            

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NFCActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This is a lot of text. I am not sure if anyone is going to read it... Please try to narrow down the question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't meant to cause efforts, just tried to be precise and provide all relevant information. I have shortened the post. Hope it's more concise now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody is facing a similar problem: I was finally able to overcome the issue described above by setting the `android:launchMode` property for the `MainActivity` to `singleInstance`.